# How to make a draggable item draggable again AFTER it has been dropped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

This is my current code.

I would like `#spanner` to become droppable again after it has been dropped on the one of the `.nuts`

```
// SPANNER PICKUP

$("#spanner").draggable();

// NUTS DROPPABLE

var unscrewed = 0

$(".nuts").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        unscrewed ++;
        $(this).fadeOut();
        checkUnscrewed()
    }
});
```

Comment: Check for the draggable element https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This example  is not clear enough, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Made a test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/o8ftc1rr/